# Select the content of attribute value of input tag by XPATH

Tags: c#, parsing, xpath, tags

I have an input tag and I want to get the value inside of that tag. I tried `selectsinglenode(//input/@value)` and `Attributes[]` and `getAttributename` in DocumentNode of Agilitypack in C#, but they did not work.

```
<input type=hidden" value="S1" name="code1" />
```

I want to get the S1 value of this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code:

```
HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@value]").Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Hope this helps,